# Move an SCNNode and make it look at the same point it was looking at before moving

Tags: scenekit

I created SCNNodes with a SCNCylinder geometry to represent lines between points (ie: SCNSphere).
It does work very well.

Now i am moving one point, and want to move the 2 lines that were "linked" to this point. Lets concentrate on only the first line for simplicity.

To move a line:

1. I move the center of the cylinder node and update its length.
2. I use simdLook to change its orientation.

`lineNode.simdLook(at: targetPoint, up: shapeRootNode.WorldUp, localFront: lineNode.WorldUp)`

The line correctly moves to the center point, and has the correct length, but gets an incorrect orientation every 2 calls. After the 1st call it is correct. After the 2nd call it is perpendicular to the orientation it should have. After the 3rd call it is correct. Etc...

✅ I verified that targetPoint is correct, the worldUp of the scene (on its root node) is constant. So this leaves the worldUp of the line node ❌.

This 3rd parameter of simdLook is a local front. As a SCNCylinder is built vertically, its local worldUp is the line direction. so it should work ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a workaround.

I reset lineNode.Orientation to SCNQuaternion's Identity before using Look.

So the issue is `Look` incorrectly uses the node current's `Orientation` property to compute the new ... `Orientation` property for the same node!

This is silly.